# Load dynamically image using require function react

Tags: reactjs, image, dynamic

I've some problem to understand how works "require" function who allow to load image on a react project.
I know we use it to generate a context module but I don't know what it allows or not in syntax.

Example :

```
const getData=()=>{
    let data = require('../data/login.json');
    data.map((item) => {
        setImg(require(`../images/${item.img}`))
        setAlias(item.alias)
        setEmail(item.email)
        setPwd(item.pwd)
    })
  }
```

```
<Avatar
  alt={alias}
  src={img}
  sx={{ width: 56, height: 56 }}
/>
```

The "require" function works well but if I add the path with a variable like that :

```
const getData=()=>{
    let data = require('../data/login.json');
    let path = '../images/'
    data.map((item) => {
        setImg(require(path + item.img))
        setAlias(item.alias)
        setEmail(item.email)
        setPwd(item.pwd)
    })
  }
```

That launch an error :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../images/avatar.jpg'
    webpackEmptyContext pages|sync:2
    getData Profile.js:29
    getData Profile.js:28
    Profile Profile.js:37
    React 8
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
    js scheduler.development.js:571
    js scheduler.development.js:633
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 24
```

Why the context generated is empty when I use a variable for the path ?

Thanks.